# Unable to close HttpClient connection in Silverlight

Tags: c#, http, silverlight

I'm unable to close a HttpClient connection in Silverlight using HttpWebResponse.Close(). In Wireshark I still see all the packets being received from my stream. If I use the exact same code in WPF or a console application the stream will close. Is this a bug for Silverlights HttpClient?

**Console Application:**

```
class Program
{
    static BinaryReader BinaryReader;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetData();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the stream...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        BinaryReader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the program..");
    }

    static async void GetData()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://212.42.54.136:8008/mjpg/video.mjpg?camera=1", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        BinaryReader = new BinaryReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: @EZI Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: Seems like a timing issue. At the time you hit enter *BinaryReader* may be null (`httpClient.GetAsync` may be still executing)